# pil draw text with different colors

Tags: python, text, python-imaging-library, draw

Hi to draw three different text with different options for ex:

1. text-number-1 , font=arial, color=red
2. text-number-2 , font=veranda, color=blue, size=30
3. text-number-3 , font=tahoma, color=green, size=40 , align=center

text must go in new lines.

```
def pil_image(request):
text = request.GET.get('text', None)
font = str(request.GET.get('font', 'arial'))
fontsize = int(request.GET.get('fontsize', '20'))
textcolor = str(request.GET.get('textcolor', '000'))

import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, textwrap

img = Image.open('media/text/transparent.png')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()
w, h = img.size

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

img.putdata(newData)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("media/text/fonts/" + font + ".ttf", fontsize, encoding="unic")


margin = offset = 40
for line in textwrap.wrap(text, width=48):
    w, h = draw.textsize(line)
    draw.text((margin, offset), line, font=font, fill='#'+textcolor)
    offset += font.getsize(line)[1]

del draw 

img.save("media/text/custom.png", "PNG")

return HttpResponse("<img src='/media/text/custom.png'>");
```

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you've tried or at least conceptually what you are having a problem understanding or solving.  SO isn't here to do assignments for you.

Comment: added code, that i use now

Answer (score 24):

The "fill" parameter should be a tuple with 4 number, as you use a RGBA colormode.

For opaque red:

```
draw.text((margin, offset), line, font=font, fill=(255,0,0,255) )
```

Comment: It is BGRA not RGBA (i.e (255,0,0,255) is blue, not red)

Answer (score 5):

Use hex value for colour, as follows:

```
draw.text((margin, offset), line, font=font, fill="#000")
```

Answer (score 3):

simply do this

```
# thicker border
draw.text((x-1, y-1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x+1, y-1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x-1, y+1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((x+1, y+1), text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
```